# Jupyter Notebook - Ipyregulartable output not shown

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to use the Ipyregular widget in my Jupyter Notebook. This is a simple example:

```
import ipyregulartable as rt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(25) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([5, 4]), columns =["A", "B", "C", "D"]) 
df = df.round({"A":1, "B":2, "C":3, "D":4}) 

w = rt.RegularTableWidget(rt.NumpyDataModel(np.random.random((10, 10))))
w
```

But nothing is shown when I execute the code. Any idea, why this could happen and nothing is shown? When I run print("Test") it works, so it must have to do with using the widget.

Following the advice in the answer:
It does not show the table, see the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try some validation before using this widget:

1. Widget Installation

```
pip install ipyregulartable
```

2. Import

```
import ipyregulartable as rt
```

3. Widget Initialization: Double-check that the widget is properly initialized and displayed in your notebook.

```
# Option 1 - Using display function
from IPython.display import display
display(w)

# Option 2 - Writing the widget object as the last line in the cell
w
```

If still not working then please post it here.

Comment: I edited my question regarding to your answer.